# How to replace complex lateral join subquery with window functions in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, lateral-join

We're having some logic to detect duplicate posts in out system. The query looks similar to this:

```
select *
from posts outer lateral join
(select id
from posts where id != outer.id and 
(tag = outer.tag) and
(date = outer.date) and
(title = outer.title) and
...//other criterias with and/or conditions
)
```

What would be the way to replace this lateral join with window function. For single field, it's easy

```
select id, array_agg(id) over (partition by title)
from posts
```

The query above will of course get all posts with the same title, but how to extend this to around 10 criteria combined with and/or operators?

I'm pretty new to window functions in PG, so any help is appreciated

EDIT:

Including the exact query and script for creating table:

```
select *
from posts p join lateral
(select id
from posts where id != p.id and 
(tag is null or p.tag is null or tag = p.tag) and
(date is null or p.date is null or date = p.date) and
(title = p.title) and
(category_id is null or p.category_id is null or category_id = p.category_id)) p2 on true
```

Sample table creation:

```
create table if not exists posts(
   id serial primary key,
   title varchar,
   tag varchar,
   category_id bigint,
   date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
)
```

Comment: You'd need to create some expression that would map every post to a canonical representation

Comment: Can you show how "or conditions" would work?

Comment: Your example should be syntactically correct, so that we can run it without doing reconstructive surgery.  If the OR operators are important to your problem, then you should include them in the example concretely.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Please find the query in the edit part of the question. Does that make sense?

Comment: Should that be `(tag is null and p.tag is null) or tag = p.tag` or do you really mean `tag is null or p.tag is null or tag = p.tag`, i.e. a NULL matches anything?

Comment: @Bergi I am afraid so. With your suggestion, all it would need to get duplicate posts is a simple `SELECT array_agg(id) FROM posts GROUP BY title, tag, category_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2`. If I am correct, I do not think what @aldm wants to do it possible. As the keyword `PARTITION` suggests, you need to build something akin to an [equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) for it to work i.e. you cannot have 3 records R1, R2, R3 with R1~R2, R2~R3 but not R1~R3 (e.g. if the tag for R2 is null but not R1 and R3); this breaks transitivity.

Comment: @Atmo exactly my thoughts

Answer (score 0):

According to the edit part of your question, I understand that for a given post, you looks for any existing post with a different id, with the exactly same title, and for the other columns, with a NULL value or with the same value if not NULL. If this is rigth, then :

First I would suggest to replace your query with a `INNER JOIN LATERAL ... ON True` which in fact corresponds to a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` clause by the same query with a simple `INNER JOIN` clause which will facilitate the query planner :

```
SELECT *
  FROM posts AS p
 INNER JOIN posts AS pd
    ON pd.id <> p.id
   AND pd.title = p.title
   AND COALESCE(pd.tag = p.tag, True)
   AND COALESCE(pd.category_id = p.category_id, True)
   AND COALESCE(pd.date = p.date, True)
```

Then, in order to find the duplicates without `JOIN`, you can use `aggregate` functions with a `DISTINCT` clause after having `GROUP BY title` (the DISTINCT clause is not allowed for window functions) :

```
SELECT title
     , array_agg(id)
     , count(*)
       <> count(DISTINCT row(tag,category_id,date))
          - count(DISTINCT row(tag,category_id,date)) FILTER (WHERE tag IS NULL OR category_id IS NULL OR date IS NULL) AS duplicates 
  FROM posts
 GROUP BY title
```

In the result, the rows with `duplicates = true` correspond to the duplicates in the table according to your criteria.

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V3svdSKX).

Comment: Thanks very much. So it is not possible using window function, but this is much neater than my original query. What about the performance?

Comment: Hard to predict the performances, this will depend on many factors (query plan selected by postgres relying on indexes or not, ...). The best is to test on your environment and in case of performance issue, you can release a new question where you can share the EXPLAIN ANALYSE result of your query.